# List Items Horizontal Alignment in 2 Columns

Tags: html, css, list, alignment

I'm trying to create a 2 column unordered list. My list items will contain  tags since I want to jump to article content with this list. Any ideas on how to get it working?

Here is the JS Fiddle of the code I currently have. https://jsfiddle.net/mithrawn/od0kaw6y/

```
<section class="index-list">
  <h4> In this article</h4>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#add">Add Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#edit">Edit Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#delete">Delete Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>

.index-list { 
  background: #F9FAFA; 
  border-left: 4px solid #AAAEB7;
  margin: 3em 0; 
  padding: 15px 0px;

}

.index-list li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;    
    margin: 0.7em 25px 0em 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

This is the effect I'm trying to get.

[image]

Comment: Edited your jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/0q5acmLy/

Comment: no, not really a clean solution.  use flexbox you will have much more control of placement

Comment: interesting, op doesn't actually say that one way or the other. Seems like a bad design (imo).  The other way is more scalable.

Comment: `.column-count:2` ?

Comment: Adrian, I will try to work with that. I know it isn't optimal but I think that might just work for my very odd needs. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `column-count`

> The column-count CSS property breaks an element's content into the specified number of columns.
>
> [**MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/column-count)

```css
.index-list { 
  background: #F9FAFA; 
  border-left: 4px solid #AAAEB7;
  margin: 3em 0; 
  padding: 15px 0px 15px 20px;

}

.index-list ul {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  column-count: 2;
}

.index-list li {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
}

.index-list li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="index-list">
  <h4> In this article</h4>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#add">Add Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#edit">Edit Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#delete">Delete Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#add">Add Contact 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#edit">Edit Contact 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#delete">Delete Contact 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#add">Add Contact 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#edit">Edit Contact 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#delete">Delete Contact 2</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: My obsession for flex-box and self-challenge to avoid media queries has blinded me to simple solutions like these! Just as easy as flex-box to make responsive with a simple `@media` rule, and much much simpler. +1

Answer (score 0):

Use snippets! check out flexbox for this kind of stuff.  Makes it really easy

```css
#section{
display:flex;
}

.index-list { 
  background: #F9FAFA; 
  border-left: 4px solid #AAAEB7;
  margin: 3em 0; 
  padding: 15px 0px;

}

.index-list li {
    list-style: none;
    float: left;    
    margin: 0.7em 25px 0em 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
  <h4> In this article</h4>
  <section id='section' class="index-list">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#add">Add Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#edit">Edit Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#delete">Delete Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#add">Add Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#edit">Edit Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#delete">Delete Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: I think he is trying to get a single `<ul>`'s elements to wrap into a second column, not using two lists.

Comment: Unfortunately, that does not work because I need "In this article" to be in the grey box. I also don't want to create two <ul>'s. The image I included above is somehow getting it done without just one <ul>

Comment: it's easy to place the In this Article where you need it.  one ul is just bad design (imo).  not very scalable and may be more difficult to make responsive.

Comment: I agree but I'm a bit constrained due to our software partners

Comment: @DCR What is bad about using a single `<ul>`? It's much more semantically valid that way.

Answer (score -1):

In order to do this without tweaking your markup, use a flex-box! Set your list to be a column flex with wrap, and make sure your list items are `display: block;` and then as long as your list has a height set to wrap at, it should work fine.

```css
.index-list {
  background: #F9FAFA;
  border-left: 4px solid #AAAEB7;
  margin: 3em 0;
  padding: 15px 0px;
}

.index-list ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
  height: 150px;
}

.index-list li {
  list-style: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 0.7em 25px 0em 0;
  display: block;
  /* width: 100%; <-- Removed, otherwise they will push the next column off the right side */
}

/* As a bonus: you can add this to make your links take up the full space: */
.index-list a {
  display: block;
}

/* And this for some hover-y goodness: */
.index-list a:hover {
  background-color: #E9EAEA;
}
```

```html
<section class="index-list">
  <h4>In this article</h4>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#add">Add Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#edit">Edit Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#delete">Delete Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#add">Add Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#edit">Edit Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#delete">Delete Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#add">Add Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#edit">Edit Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="#delete">Delete Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Then just fiddle with your padding and margins to make things spaced to your liking :)

Comment: This method requires a **fixed height**.